# Magento 3 - There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento, pdo, ftp

I'm trying to put one magento application in FTP, but I'm having this issue:

[Problem print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCSL0.png)

Nothing that I see on internet helped me, can someone help, please? Thanks since now.

Comment: The MySql Service is down or there is not connection between Magento and MySql. You will need to make a double check in the app/etc/local.xml file

Comment: How can I double check? What is this? Sorry for my little knowledge.

Comment: Inside your Magento installation (folder), you should look for a file in the path app/etc/local.xml, in that file, you will need to set the server params like "ip address, user, and password"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?